# How do you use awk to set column position?

Tags: awk

My problem is pretty simple, but I can't seem to find a solution after searching. I had a short line of code that I used previously for this but sadly have lost the code and knowledge to build it again myself.

I need an awk code to ensure the second column in a dataframe always starts at the 10th position. So, for example, with a normal single space delimiter, my data would look like:

```
123987 9876653
123456 6519849
234567 6516515
5648 6516578
123 7896511
```

What I want to achieve is this:

```
123987   9876653
123456   6519849
234567   6516515
5648     6516578
123      7896511
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You'll want [`printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start the 2nd field in column 10 you can force the 1st field to take up the first 9 columns, eg:

```
$ awk '{printf "%-9s%s\n",$1,$2}' data
123987   9876653
123456   6519849
234567   6516515
5648     6516578
123      7896511
```